# XML basic construction of a request

Tags: java, javascript, xml, xsd

I have sample XSD here, and my question is how can I can create an XML request on this sample xsd element?

```
 '<xsd:element name="line1" type="tns:SearchLine"/>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to do it programmatically but I can suggest you to use eclipse.

1. Explore your project and select your xsd file in eclipse.
2. Right click on it and select generate.
3. Use the option generate xml.
4. Select a root element and your are done.